# ASP.Net MVC: How to configure route for action with 2 parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routeconfig

I have Get actions in my controllers which have two parameters.
I call them from Razor views like this using JS functions:

```
function deleteAddress(addressId) {
    url = '@Url.Action("Delete", "Addresses",new { addressId = "3",actionRouteAfterActionFinish="SelectAddress"})';
    openLink(url);
}
```

And here is declaration of my action inside controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int addressId,string actionRouteAfterActionFinish){
   ...
   ...
}
```

When I add below Attribute route it works well and both paramters are passed correctly from Razor view to `Delete` action:

```
[Route("Addresses/Delete/{addressId}/{actionRouteAfterActionFinish}")]
```

But when I try to use below `RouteConfig` it does not work and 2nd parameter is set `null` when method is get called from Razor view. I wonder how can I rewrite `RouteConfig` to manage actions with two parameters?

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
//enabling attribute routing
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Intro", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "TwoParamterAction",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{parameter1}/{paramter2}"
);
```

I reordered `Default` rule with `TwoParamterAction` rule but it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the argument names do not match. Arguments in the route url can have a different order than the method arguments.

Because of that, the names must match.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "TwoParamterAction",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{addressId}/{actionRouteAfterActionFinish}"
);
```

That should work, since the names match.

Comment: So why the first paramter `addressId` is passed correctly to `addressId` although parameter name is `id` in `Default` route?